# Apache Kafka Consumer Connection

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am looking at the docs of [Apache Kafka.](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html)

The consumer connects to the Kafka by using the IP address/port of zookeepers.

Is it possible to use the IP address/port of broker?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when using the Simple consumer API you get to manage consumption directly from the brokers. See usage example [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.

The consumer connects to the Kafka by using the IP address/port of zookeepers. What you point is High-level API

And connecting to broker directly points Low-level API

Maybe [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example) can help you